# the line that cause odfWeave-generated odt file to be considered as corrupted

Tags: r, odf

I have tried `odfWeave` a bit, nice app. But at the very beginning, even I tried exactly as the example provided in the manual, I can't generate any file.

I have searched a bit inside the odt file and found a statement inside the `content.xml` cause the problem, it is:

`text:bullet-char="<U+25CF>"`

what is the statement actually? how can I fix that in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem with odfWeave, which was traced back to the locale not being utf8 (see http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e10/help/10/05/4247.html).

If you run `Sys.getlocale()` this will tell you what locale R is running.  If I remember correctly, setting it to en_US.UTF-8 worked.

Alternativley, when running the example, comment out (or just don't execute) the line;

```
basicStyles$wideBullet$bulletChar="\342\234\224"
```

which sets the bullet character to use.

Comment: any advice on setting the locale to en_US.UTF-8? Here's what I get when trying to set the locale: > `Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored`

Comment: I also have exactly the same problem as you do

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember whether I managed to change the locale.   I think I was testing odfweave so just omitted the command setting the bullet character.  I haven't done any more testing since.